# How do I get rid of color kwarg errors?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm absolutely stumped as to why I'm getting this error.
Any help will be appreciated!

This is the error info:

File "C:/Python27/Scripts/Lab08realdeal.py", line 23, in 
    plt.hist(count,range=20,color = 'red')

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2896, in hist
    stacked=stacked, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 5603, in hist
    raise ValueError("color kwarg must have one color per dataset")

ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per dataset

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def loadContaminantFrequencies(contaminant, fileInfo):
 count= 0  
 for line in fileInfo: 
    if contaminant == line[0]:
      count = count+1

 return count 

ifile = open('air_samples.csv',"rb")
fileInfo = csv.reader(ifile)
count = ("Benzene", fileInfo)
counts = [count,count]


plt.hist(count,range=20,color = 'red')
plt.xlabel("CountOfChemical")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.axes([0,3000,0,1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: This may come from a `type` problem, and you may want to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60259377/12910854

Answer (score 0):

`hist()` takes either an array or a sequence of arrays as a parameter. If it gets a sequence, it tries to plot several histograms, one for each array in the sequence. Your first parameter, `count`, is a 2-element tuple, which is recognized as 2 separate datasets. Therefore `hist()` wants `color` kwarg to also have 2 elements, but it can only find one, `'red'`, hence the error.

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but perhaps the correct call is

```
plt.hist(fileInfo,range=20,color = 'red')
```

(because I can't imagine how one would plot a histogram of the string `"Benzene"`)

*Edit:* My answer assumed that `fileInfo` is something histogram-able, which it apparently isn't *(that's why you should always try to post self-contained examples)*. Not that it matters in terms of the original question anyway, the answer does not depend on it.

According to the docs of the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, you need to extract the data first. Again, since *I don't have all the information*, I'll assume that the data in your CSV file is already good to go (that is, has one column of floats).

```
fileInfo = csv.reader(ifile)
count = numpy.array([float(row[0]) for row in fileInfo])

plt.hist(count,range=20,color = 'red')
```

Please try to resolve any following problems yourself, or at least create a separate question.

Comment: I'm supposed to read in information from a .csv file with a bunch of chemicals and their concentrations and frequency values. once I have collected this frequency information, by calling a function, for Benzene, and drawing a red histogram plot (with 20 bars) using that frequency data.

Comment: And when I apply the correction you've shown me, I get a new error


 File "C:/Python27/Scripts/Lab08realdeal.py", line 23, in <module>
    plt.hist(fileInfo,range = 20,color = 'red')

 
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2896, in hist
    stacked=stacked, **kwargs)

 
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5578, in hist
    if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) or not iterable(x[0]):


TypeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Answer (score -1):

If you just delete attribute `color = 'red'` everything will probably work ok.