# ValueError: "color kwarg must have one color per dataset"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset regarding some used cars from eBay, which I tried to plot after I edited the dataset as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./autos.csv.bz2", encoding = "iso8859-1")
df = df.drop(["dateCrawled", "abtest", "dateCreated", "nrOfPictures", "lastSeen", "postalCode", "seller", "offerType"], axis = 1)

import numpy as np

df["monthOfRegistration"] = np.where(df["monthOfRegistration"] == 0, 6, df["monthOfRegistration"])


df["registration"] = df["yearOfRegistration"] + (df["monthOfRegistration"] - 1) / 12

df = df.drop(["yearOfRegistration", "monthOfRegistration"], axis = 1)


df = df.drop(df[df["price"] == 0].index)
df = df.drop(df[df["powerPS"] == 0].index)


print(df["notRepairedDamage"].unique())
print(df["notRepairedDamage"])

df["notRepairedDamage"] = np.where(df["notRepairedDamage"] == "ja", 1, df["notRepairedDamage"])
df["notRepairedDamage"] = np.where(df["notRepairedDamage"] == "nein", 0, df["notRepairedDamage"])


df = df[df["notRepairedDamage"].notnull()]
```

I tried to plot the data with `matplotlib` using `seaborn.pairplot` but got the following error:

> ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per dataset

I do only get the plots with the relative frequencies of the first 3 lines, all the other graphs are empty, also relative frequencies in line 4 and 5.

[Matplotlib seaborn, example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6DCX.jpg)

```
df = df[(df["price"] < 100000) & (df["powerPS"] < 2000)

from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

import seaborn as sns

g = sns.pairplot(df)
```

I assume that something did go wrong when I edited my dataset.
Is there anyone who could help me? That would be great! Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't exactly see where the problem is, but I guess that you can spot it by printing df each time you modify it. You can also try to call pairplot on your raw dataset to be sure that the problem comes from your post-processing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint! I did that and until the code df["notRepairedDamage"] = np.where(df["notRepairedDamage"] == "ja", 1, df["notRepairedDamage"]) I get graphs with "Price", "powerPS", "Kilometer" and "Registration". As soon as I execute the next line df["notRepairedDamage"] = np.where(df["notRepairedDamage"] == "nein", 0, df["notRepairedDamage"])
 and try to plot it, I get the same 5 graphs (the diagonals are right, the other graphs are emtpy) as upon again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError("color kwarg must have one color per dataset")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757386/valueerrorcolor-kwarg-must-have-one-color-per-dataset)

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment, an example snippet, which hopefully can help you. Maybe the issue is with IPython? Unfortunately, I do not know. Having your dataset available would definitely help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

a = pd.DataFrame()
a['One'] = [1, 3, 3, 2, 1]
a['Two'] = ['ja', 'ja', 'nein', 'ja', 'nein']
a['Two'] = np.where(a['Two'] == 'ja', 1, a['Two'])
a['Two'] = np.where(a['Two'] == 'nein', 0, a['Two'])
a = a[a['Two'].notnull()]
print(a)
sns.pairplot(a)
plt.show()
```

This prints

```
   One Two
0    1   1
1    3   1
2    3   0
3    2   1
4    1   0
```

and displays

[image]

Comment: I do not exactly know why but I do also get the same error as before. Maybe, it is because I use Spyder from Anaconda? And, the command import matplotlib.pyplot as plt does not work in my case, so I need to write instead the code: from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline'). Can you now maybe imagine, why I do get an error?

Comment: Which OS are you running Anaconda on? It is definitely first task to fix your installation, as the problem may come from it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that `pairplot` only accepts some pandas types in the `PairGrid`: `float` or `int`, but not `Object` or `Int64` for exemple (at least for some versions of matplotlib and/or seaborn: 3.0.3 and 0.9.0 respectivly generates that error).

Using `.astype('float')` to modify the concerned series before plotting in the following exemple solves the problem as `a.One` is set to `Int64` and `a.Two` is initially an `Object` type:

```
a = pd.DataFrame()
a['One'] = [1, 3, 3, 2, 1]
a['One']=a['One'].astype('Int64')
a['Two'] = ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
a['Two'] = np.where(a['Two'] == 'yes', 1, a['Two'])
a['Two'] = np.where(a['Two'] == 'no', 0, a['Two'])
a['One']=a['One'].astype('int')
a['Two']=a['Two'].astype('int')
sns.pairplot(a)
plt.show()
```

Remark that if you have some `NaN` in your dataframe, `float` is the only option as `Int64` accepts missing values but not the `Int` type.