# ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per data set. 891 data sets and 1 colors were provided

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to use sns.pairplot with DataFrame.
Using the below code to do the same. I have tried every possible way I know. Stuck with this for the past 2 days. Please help.
Thanks.

```
graph_9= sns.pairplot(train_set_x)
```

Getting below error:

> ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per data set. 891 data sets and 1 color were provided

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: This may come from a `type` problem, and you may want to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60259377/12910854

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and it appeared my data was containing `inf`. You can use `train_set_x.describe()` to see if your data contains inf. If so, report to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477979/dropping-infinite-values-from-dataframes-in-pandas) to remove those.